# How do I break a long equation?

Tags: equations, line-breaking

I have a long equation that it was hard for me to break so that it appears professional. How can I do it?

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        &\mathbb{P}\left( \left. Z_{1}\in dx_{1},Z_{2}\in dx_{2},\cdots ,Z_{n}\in
            dx_{n}\right\vert Z_{n+1}=x_{n+1}\right) \\
        \qquad &=f_{Z_{n+1}}\left(x_{n+1}\right) ^{-1}\left[ \mathbb{P}\left( \left\{ Z_{1}\in dx_{1},Z_{2}\in
            dx_{2},\cdots ,Z_{n}\in dx_{n}\right\} \cap \left\{ Z_{n+1}=x_{n+1}\right\} \right) \right]  \\
        =f_{Z_{n+1}}\left( x_{n+1}\right) ^{-1}\times \mathbb{\pi } \\
        =e^{-x_{n+1}}dx_{1}\cdots dx_{n+1}/f_{Z_{n+1}}\left( x_{n+1}\right)  \\
        =n!x^{-n}dx_{1}\cdots dx_{n}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not far. Remove all `\left` and `\right` tokens that only do bad, in this context; there's just a pair of brackets that asks for being a bit larger (with `\bigl` and `\bigr`).

Also some help is needed for the dots in the final two lines; use `\mid` instead of `\vert`, for better spacing and don't forget `\,` after the factorial.

Last thing: I added empty superscripts to `f_{Z_{n+1}}`, so the subscript is slightly moved down.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts} % for \mathbb

\DeclareMathOperator{\PR}{\mathbb{P}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\PR(Z_{1}\in dx_{1},Z_{2}\in dx_{2},\dots ,Z_{n}\in dx_{n}\mid Z_{n+1}=x_{n+1})
\\
&\quad =f^{}_{Z_{n+1}}(x_{n+1}) ^{-1}\bigl[
   \PR( \{ Z_{1}\in dx_{1},Z_{2}\in dx_{2},\dots,Z_{n}\in dx_{n}\}
\\
&\qquad\qquad \cap\{Z_{n+1}=x_{n+1}\})\bigr]  \\
&\quad =f^{}_{Z_{n+1}}( x_{n+1}) ^{-1}\times \pi \\
&\quad =e^{-x_{n+1}}dx_{1}\dotsm dx_{n+1}/f^{}_{Z_{n+1}}(x_{n+1})  \\
&\quad =n!\,x^{-n}dx_{1}\dotsm dx_{n}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why not an outer `multline` with all lines but the first either `split` or `aligned`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I prefer the equals signs to be near the left side, like if the first line were `X&=\PR(...)`

Answer (score 4):

Some suggestions:

- Keep using a `split` environment, but provide alignment points on all lines
- Use an `aligned` environment to the right of the `=` symbol in row 2 to break up that line into two separate lines
- Don't overuse `\left` and `\right`; in fact, for the equations at hand, they're not needed *at all*.
- Don't use `\cdots` for the equations at hand. Instead, use `\dots` in the first two rows and `\dotsm` ("multiplicate dots") in the final two rows.
- There is no "Blackboard Bold" version of `\pi`; hence, `\mathbb{\pi }` is the same as `\pi`. If you must produce a bold version of the symbol, write `\boldsymbol{\pi}`; alternatively, load the `bm` package and write `\bm{\pi}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,bm}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
   \mathbb{P}(
        &Z_{1}\in dx_{1},Z_{2}\in dx_{2},\dots, Z_{n}\in
            dx_{n} \mid Z_{n+1}=x_{n+1}) \\
        &=\!\begin{aligned}[t] 
            f_{Z_{n+1}}^{} (x_{n+1})^{-1} \bigl[ \mathbb{P}(\{
            &Z_{1}\in dx_{1}, Z_{2}\in dx_{2}, \dots , Z_{n}\in dx_{n}\} \\
            &\cap \{ Z_{n+1}=x_{n+1}\} ) \bigr]
        \end{aligned}\\
        &=f_{Z_{n+1}}( x_{n+1})^{-1} \times \bm{\pi} \\
        &=e^{-x_{n+1}}\,dx_{1}\dotsm dx_{n+1} / f_{Z_{n+1}}( x_{n+1})  \\
        &=n!\,x^{-n}\,dx_{1}\dotsm dx_{n}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I propose a solution with `multline` and `aligned`. The geometry package yields more sensible margins, if you don't use margin notes. Finally, I simplified your code, using the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` commad form `mathtools`: I defined a `\Prob`+`\given` command for conditional probabilities, and a `\set` command, which have  variable-sized delimiters if used in their starred version, or with an option (`\big, \Big`, &c.):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsfonts} % for 'dcases' environment
\usepackage{xparse} \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\Prob[1]{\mathbb P}(){}{
\newcommand\given{\nonscript\:\delimsize\vert\nonscript\:}
#1}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\set}[1]\{\}{\setargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{;}}m} {\setargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargsaux}{mm}
{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\nonscript\,#1\nonscript\,}{\nonscript\,#1\nonscript\;{;}
\nonscript\:\allowbreak #2\nonscript\,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
  \Prob{ Z_{1} \in dx_{1},Z_{2} \in dx_{2}, \dots ,Z_{n}\in
    dx_{n}\given Z_{n+1} =x_{n+1}} \\
  \begin{aligned}
      & =f_{Z_{n+1}}\left(x_{n+1}\right) ^{-1}\left[ \Prob*{\set*{ Z_{1} \in dx_{1},Z_{2} ∈
    dx_{2}, \dots ,Z_{n} \in dx_{n}} \cap \set*{ Z_{n+1}=x_{n+1}}} \right] \\
      & =f_{Z_{n+1}}\left( x_{n+1}\right) ^{-1} \times \mathbb{\pi } \\
      & =e^{-x_{n+1}}dx_{1}\dotsm dx_{n+1}/f_{Z_{n+1}}\left( x_{n+1}\right) \\
      & =n!\,x^{-n}dx_{1} \dotsm dx_{n}
  \end{aligned}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's typographically appropriate to use `\cdots` in comma-delimited lists -- see rows 1 and 2. Consider using either `\dots` or `\dotsc` ("dots between commas"). Also, `\mathbb{\pi}` is suspect.

Comment: @Mico: I just took the code from the O.P and didn't notice. But you're righht, I'll update my answer. Thanks for pointing it